# Parameter not being passed from code

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint

I am working on a simple SharePoint page that gets data from a dropdown and passes them to a PowerShell script as a parameter. But I get an error when debugging, and I found out that there are no parameters being passed to the script.

The script file is placed inside my layouts folder, with a structure like this:

```psh
Param($param1, $param2, $param3)
```

What I am doing from my C# code is I read the file using a `StreamReader` and then run the script using this code:

```cs
using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create()) {
    powerShell.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn(_powershell,out snapInException);           
    powerShell.Commands.AddScript(the read script form streamreader); 
    powerShell.AddParameter("param1", SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/");
    powerShell.AddParameter("param2", selectedText1);
    powerShell.AddParameter("param3", selectedText2);

    try {
        var results = powerShell.Invoke();
    } catch (Exception exp) { }                     
}
```

I am getting an error that my parameters are null and I don't know why my parameters are not passing. Am I doing something wrong?

Also, I tried running the ps1 script using this one:

```cs
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceCOnfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceCOnfig);
runspace.Open();

RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
Command myCommand = new Command(script path);

CommandParameter param1 = new CommandParameter("param1", SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/");
CommandParameter param2 = new CommandParameter("param2", selectedText1);
CommandParameter param3 = new CommandParameter("param3", selectedText2);
myCommand.Parameters.Add(param1);
myCommand.Parameters.Add(param2);
myCommand.Parameters.Add(param3);

pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);
```

and I get this error:

> 'path_to_script.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Is `path_to_script.ps1` an absolute path? Your second example seems fine, sounds like it just can't resolve the path to the script

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen, i made it work! apparently i only get this error when my parameter has special characters in it :(